# Jira - webhook only fires first time transition is ran on prod server, fires every time on dev server

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have a Jira WebHook that only fires the first time a transition happens on our production server, but fires every time the transition happens on our dev server. The Jira logs don't even show it trying to fire for a second time in prod. The webhooks are configured the same way, and the transitions are configured the same way. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check that the same transition takes place the "second time".

Comment: It is the exact same transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volodymyr was correct! The transition names were the same, but the transition IDs were different.